# How do I deenergize a cctv power supply? (altronix Sav4d)

Tags: electrical, power-supply, cctv

How do I deenergize a cctv power supply. I have an altronix Sav4d PSU and the manual  says I need to deenergize the power supply before working on it but doesn’t contain any instructions. How can I deenergize my PSU?
[image: PSU interior]

Comment: I gotta say, if you don't know how to deenergize electronics, I'm not sure you've got the knowledge to work on it successfully. That's not intended to be an insult, but to maybe help save you the money of replacing the thing instead of just paying someone to fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Deenergize just means disconnect the power. So either unplug the power cord or pull out the grey connector on the left.